# Wrap span tag around sentence with Javascript

Tags: javascript, tags, addition

I need to locate a sentence on my page and wrap it with a span tag (with a class).

This is my page:

```
<body>
<h1>Home Page</h1>
<p>Welcome to the homepage of the site. Enjoy your stay</p>
</body>
```

Using Javascript, I would like to transform the P content to:

```
<p><span class="mySpan">Welcome to the homepage</span> of the site. Enjoy your stay</p>
```

Comment: It's not clear if you want to change the html element from P to SPAN or just to style the P element.

Comment: @jgpATs2w Basically this is the result I'd be looking for: `<p><span class="mySpan">Welcome to the homepage</span> of the site. Enjoy your stay</p>`

Comment: @Alex K.:Since it's not tagged with jquery, the answers may differ.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do:

1. read the html using .innerHtml or jQuery.html().
2. parse the data
3. write the data back using .innerHtml or jQuery.html()

You can do the parsing using RegEx and various other ways..
Here is a simple example of doing so.

```
var html = $("p").html();
html = "<span>" + html;
html = html.replace("homepage","homepage</span>");
$("p").html(html);
```

here is a working jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/QjDvR/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to avoid using jquery, try this:

```
<script>  
  P = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
  search = 'Welcome to the homepage';
  s = P[0].innerHTML.replace(search,'<span class="mySpan">' + search +'</span>');
  P[0].innerHTML =s;
</script> <!-- always locate script at the end of the body -->
</body>
```

BUT, to enhance it, you should consider to include the ID attribute to the element, and select this element with the method document.getElementById('the_id').